# Fault code [REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED]. Reason [TotalRequests Limit exceeded.]

Tags: api, salesforce

What is the salesforce API Request MAX limit per second, minute, and hourly bases? default license supports 15,000 requests per 24 hours. if we want to know more details with respect to hourly how many API requests are consumed, can we verify in the salesforce portal?

if we plan to increase the Daily basis API limit, what is the procedure to follow and Is there any additional cost required?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:
Based on number of user license the api limit increases.
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008mDCIAY